# Cookie not generated in browser on ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, session-cookies

I have an application separated into 2. Backend asp.net core web application running on port localhost/5001. Frontend react js application running on port localhost/3000. Both are configured to run on https. When logging in, the cookie is not generated, but the login is successful.

This is the ConfigureService method in Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 5001;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        // services.AddSession();
        services.AddSession(opts =>
        {
            opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(enableCors, builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
    }
```

And this is the Configure method in Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseCors(enableCors);
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

This is the backend login endpoint

```
[Route("login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (user != null)
        {

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return new JsonResult(true, new JsonSerializerSettings());
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult(false, new JsonSerializerSettings());
    }
```

And this is the frontend call

```
 handleLogin(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const data = new FormData(event.target);

 fetch('https://localhost:5001/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
 })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data)
      history.push('/home');
  });
 }
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Put _UseAuthentication_ middleware between _UseCookiePolicy_ and _UseCors_ and ensure that you have _Set-Cookie_ header in your response.

Answer (score 0):

In default, fetch api does not implement cookie.

Try this

```
fetch('https://localhost:5001/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  credentials: "same-origin"
 })
  .then(response => {
    document.cookie = `coo_key=${response.headers.get('cookiee_key')};max-age=604800;domain=yoururl.com`;
    return response.json();
 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data)
      history.push('/home');
  });
 }
```

While this will only let you access the cookie generated by api. You have to manually set it on then

```
document.cookie = `coo_key=${response.headers.get('cookiee_key')};max-age=604800;domain=yoururl.com`
```

TLDR
The generated cookie from api will not automatically bind in your react app. if they are separated. you need to enable same-origin and set the cookie by yourself

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change anything